# How do I turn the "_shares" into ERC20 Tokens in this contract?

Tags: remix, tokens, erc-20

I was tinkering a bit with the following Vault contract. The contract works like that: Deposit Token X and receive minted shares. Withdraw Token X for the amount of shares you are holding and the shares get burned.

I want the shares to be a ERC20 Token(with a name, symbol etc.) but I am having the issue that once the shares are generated I cannot send them anywhere. Can anyone help me what I have to add?

Here is the affirmentioned code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract Vault {
    IERC20 public immutable token;

    uint public totalSupply;
    string public symbol;
    string public name;
    uint8 public decimals;
    mapping(address => uint) public balanceOf;

    constructor(address _token) {
        token = IERC20(_token);
        name = "VaultWithdraw";
        symbol = "wdraw";
        decimals = 0;
    }

    function _mint(address _to, uint _shares) private {
        totalSupply += _shares;
        balanceOf[_to] += _shares;
    }

    function _burn(address _from, uint _shares) private {
        totalSupply -= _shares;
        balanceOf[_from] -= _shares;
    }

    function deposit(uint _amount) external {
        /*
        a = amount
        B = balance of token before deposit
        T = total supply
        s = shares to mint

        (T + s) / T = (a + B) / B 

        s = aT / B
        */
        uint shares;
        if (totalSupply == 0) {
            shares = _amount;
        } else {
            shares = (_amount * totalSupply) / token.balanceOf(address(this));
        }

        _mint(msg.sender, shares);
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
    }

    function withdraw(uint _shares) external {
        /*
        a = amount
        B = balance of token before withdraw
        T = total supply
        s = shares to burn

        (T - s) / T = (B - a) / B 

        a = sB / T
        */
        uint amount = (_shares * token.balanceOf(address(this))) / totalSupply;
        _burn(msg.sender, _shares);
        token.transfer(msg.sender, amount);
    }
}
```

IERC20:

```
interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);

    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool);

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);

    function approve(address spender, uint amount) external returns (bool);

    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint amount
    ) external returns (bool);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint amount);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint amount);
}
```

Comment: "...but I am having the issue that once the shares are generated I cannot send them anywhere..". Can you clarify this phrase and your logic? When you use this statement 'token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);' I think that's you're sending shares amount to who interact with this function...

Answer (score 0):

To allow the transfer of shares your contract and make your contract fully ERC-20 compliant, you must implement the remaining logic of an [ERC20 token](https://github.com/transmissions11/solmate/blob/main/src/tokens/ERC20.sol) (i.e. `transfer`, `transferFrom`, etc.)

An even better solution would be create a vault contract that is [ERC4626 compliant](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4626). That would allow other devs to easily integrate your vault token in their application ([example 1](https://github.com/transmissions11/solmate/blob/main/src/mixins/ERC4626.sol), [example 2](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC4626.sol)).